# What's the difference between ipn_url, notify_url, callback_url and return_url?

Tags: url, paypal, payment

When we develop an application for payment API, we often hear about the ipn_url, notify_url, callback_url and return_url.

So what's the difference between them?

Comment: This is covered in the documentation

Answer (score 1):

The return_url is the url you define where customers will be redirected to review their order before they hit submit or where they land after a payment is completed; depends on your design flow.

callback_url is used to direct PayPal that you have setup which can receive the payer's shipping information from PayPal's server, generate shipping and sales tax rates based on that data, and return shipping options back to the PayPal review screen.

The notify_URL is used for IPN payment notification services

Instead of posting the links to the answers, if you go to developer.paypal.com and search for your keywords you'll find more details on how they're used and what calls you can actually use them in. Hope this helps